# Windows 10: How to unlock account if not connected to company domain

Tags: windows, vpn, authentication

I have been looking for help on this for a while but unable to find any.

We have remote workers using mainly windows 10 devices. They use a vpn connection to our company network using One-time-password. We also use O365 and have hybrid model with AD sync to Azure.

We are having issues where a remote user locks their account and is unable to log in to their device. They can't use the vpn dial option as the OTP isn't the same as their windows password (obviously). Therefore it happily authenticates the vpn connection but fails to authenticate their windows account and drops the vpn connection and says Password incorrect.

Is there a way for the device to authenticate with Azure rather than our domain controller if they can't vpn in ?

Is there a way to provide a different windows password with using the vpn option to login to the device, rather than it sending the OTP to the domain controller ?

I'm sure this must be affecting many others but surprised I can't find much on this.

Any help is appreciated.

Paul

Comment: You could perhaps create multiple accounts on the computer, each with a different authentication method.

Comment: This is a common problem.  It usually occurs when the password is changed, but it is not updated on the workstation by locking/unlocking the workstation. If that is not the scenario, you may want to provide more detail on the circumstances, such as how passwords are changed, if you use a web portal such as Azure SSPR, and the Azure AD sync type.